# How does Aid Allies affect build times?

Tags: march-of-empires

### Background

[**March of Empires**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/March_of_Empires):  *War of Lords* is a freemium game where players control a city.  The city can build buildings and train troops.  The troops can engage in wars of conquest or secure resources.  To give the game a social aspect, people can join Alliances.  Alliances are much the same thing as clans or guilds are in other games.  One can gain by promoting one's Alliance as well as doing things purely for oneself.  Members of an Alliance are allies of each other.

One specific benefit of Alliances is that when doing activities like building, training, or researching, one can ask for help.  This puts up a notice on allies' screens.  If they click it and then the Help All button, it boosts the progress by 1%.

### Question

What does it actually mean to boost progress by 1%?  Is that 1% of the whole amount?  Or 1% of the amount remaining?  Does it take effect immediately?  Or does it act over time (i.e. does it boost the speed rather than reducing the time left)?  Does it matter whether the person hits the Help button immediately?  Or does any time before it finishes have the same impact?

My goal is to figure out a strategy for using speed-up items.  These instantly take an amount of time off that remaining.  Is it better to use these before receiving help?  After?  As close to the end as possible?  Doesn't matter?  However, it is not necessary to answer this broader question.

### Calculating

This seems calculable.  Two people with voice chat (or phones) could play the game, sign up for the same Alliance, and while on the phone, one could click the button.  The person who is building can watch the progress to see what happens.

Even better, use three people.  Two start building at the same time in cities with the same settings.  One gets help and the other doesn't.  Compare times.

Answerers may of course provide their own calculation method.  I'm just suggesting this one to get people started.  If you can handle two or three accounts yourself, you may not need help.